# How to programmatically hide the wp-login.php in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-login

I managed to create the /login url to redirect me in /wp-login.php page

In my .httacces I have the following code

```
RewriteRule ^login$ wp-login.php [NC,L]
```

In the functions.php (in my custom theme) I added this

```
 add_filter('site_url',  'wplogin_filter', 10, 3);
function wplogin_filter( $url, $path, $orig_scheme )
{
 $old  = array( "/(wp-login\.php)/");
 $new  = array( "login");
 return preg_replace( $old, $new, $url, 1);
}
```

The problem is how to disallow access to wp-login.php page without disabling it.  With the solution above both url's are visible /login and /wp-login.php

How can I "hide" the wp-login.php permenantly without usign a plugin?

Comment: Any body who had a similar issue without using a plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

I once used this in my .httaccess file.

**Code:**

```
<Files "whatever.php">
require all denied
require host localhost
require ip 127.0.0.1
require ip xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa
</Files>
```

This prevents any external entry to whatever.php

Comment: This allows access from a specific ip as I see. Is there any other solution to protect wp-login.php ?

Comment: I think so, I'd say this is the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to hide it. Just redirect access to the home page - or any other page.

```
add_filter( 'login_url', 'my_redirect_login', 10, 3 );
function my_redirect_login(){
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']!='/wp-login.php') return;
    header( 'Location: '.home_url(null, 'https') );
    exit;   
}
```